# Traversing a 2D array in an angle

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

Generally we traverse the array by row or column but here I want to traverse it in an angle. 
I will try and explain what I mean,
So lets say if the angle is 45 degree then rather than row by col it would search as (0,0) then (0,1) (1,0) then (0,2) , (1,1) ,(2,0) and so on.. .(sorry could not upload an image as I am new user and not allowed to do so, may be try and imagine/draw an array that would help get what I am trying to say) 
But what will happen if the user inputs an angle like 20 degree how can we determine how to search the array.

i just wanted to know if there is any algorithm which does something similar to this? Programming language is not an issue i guess the issue is more of algoritham sort. 
Any ideas would be welcome. 
Please feel free to ask if I am not able to explain clearly what I am looking for.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy. Take an angle (let's say 45). This corresponds to a vector `v=(1, 1)` in your case. (This can be normalized to a unitary vector `(sqrt(2)/2, sqrt(2)/2)`, but this is not necessary)

For every single point in your array, you have their coordinates `(x, y)`. Simply do the scalar product of these coordinates with the vector. Let's call `f(x, y) = scalarProduct((x, y), v)`

Sort the values of `f(x, y)` and you've got the "traversing" you're looking for!

---

A real example. 
Your matrix is 3x3
The scalar products are :

(0,0).(1,1) = 0

(0,1).(1,1) = 1

(0,2).(1,1) = 2

(1,0).(1,1) = 1

(1,1).(1,1) = 2

(1,2).(1,1) = 3

(2,0).(1,1) = 2

(2,1).(1,1) = 3

(2,2).(1,1) = 4

If you order these scalar products by ascending order, you obtain the ordering (0,0), (1,0), (1,0), (2,0), (1,1), (0,2), (2,1)...

---

And if you want to do it with the angle 20, replace all occurences of `v=(1, 1)` with `v=(cos(20), sin(20))`

---

Here's an illustration of a geometrical interpretation. The scalar products correspond to the intersections of the vector v (in red) with the blue lines.

[image: Illustration]

Comment: Can you upload an image, please? Do your solution looks like a morton curve?

Comment: Definitely not a Morton curve, I think we disagree on the question of the OP.

Comment: Thank you for your image but, I thought of a 2d-diagram with Excel of the sorted points. Looks interesting, though.

Comment: @Frevez thanks a lot for that. I guess that was exactly what i was looking for.. Eventually what I want is i can easily move in between the array. Like I can easily jump from row to row-1 and col to col +1 or something like that.. so I guess by traversing the array in the fashion u have mentioned, I will write new rowNum and colNum in a cache and use that. thanks a lot man..

Answer (score 1):

For every starting point (the leftmost point of every row), use trigonometry to determine an ending point for the given angle. The tan(angle) is defined as (height difference / width of the array), so your height differece is tan(angle)*(witdh of the array). You only have to calculate the height difference once. If y+height difference is greater than the height of the array, just subtract the height (or use the modulo operator).

Now that you have a starting point and an ending point you could use Bresenham's Algorithm to determine the points in between: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You want to look for a space-filling-curve for example a morton curve or z-curve. If you want to subdivide the array in 4 tiles you may want to look for a hilbert curve or a moore curve.